# My BaseController Redirect::action is being ignored

Tags: php, laravel, controller

In my `BaseController` *(The default one which has that setupLayout function in it)* I have a construct that checks for authentication... Because every page must be logged in to use it:

```
function __Construct(ISomethingRepository $somethingRepo)
{
    $this->somethingRepository = $somethingRepo;
    $result = Request::path();
    if( $result != "not-authenticated" )
    {
        $this->CheckIfSomethingAuthenticationRequiresRedirection();
    }
}
```

and further down in my BaseController I have a function:

```
protected function CheckIfSomethingAuthenticationRequiresRedirection()
{
    if( !$this->somethingRepository->IsAuthenticated() )
    {
        return Redirect::action( 'AuthenticationController@NotAuthenticated' );
    }

    // Otherwise finish off with the normal controller stuff
}
```

When it gets to the Redirect::action... it never gets to that controllers method... It just does some crap... then ends up continuing with the original Controller (thus the authentication is broken).

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect::action() needs to be returned to the user from a public controller method in order for the redirect to occur. You have it returning to your constructor from a protected method, but then you don't do anything to return the redirect to the user's browser.

You may have to use PHP header() instead of Redirect::action(), since you probably can't return the Redirect from a constructor.

Comment: header gets ignored too! if I do a header( "Location: poo" ); it just skips merrily over it?

Comment: By the way, an answer I've previously given to someone [explains this in more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752920/laravel-redirect-within-custom-class/21754486#21754486), and offers a possible solution, though it's unlikely you'll be too happy with the situation as the answer is basically "do it in the controller's own method and nowhere else".

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 handling the validation/redirect in the constructor really isn't the proper way to do it; and I'm not sure of a way to make it work. What you SHOULD be using is route filters. I suggest going over the documentation for them again: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Comment: Routefilters.. awesome. ill check that out :) Is there a catch all so that every url is checked on authentication... because I don't want to have to write a filter for every url.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 You can basically put all of your routes inside of one route group to implement a "catch-all" http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups